# WebPack 2.1 Intro tutorial not converting import

Tags: webpack

I'm following the intro tutorial to webpack 2.1 located at https://webpack.js.org/get-started/

It's straight forward and fairly quick but the generated bundle doesn't convert `import _ from 'lodash';` to anything -- it's included as written -- so, I get an error in my web browser when I open the index.html page.

I did try to add the following packages:

- babel-loader
- babel-core
- babel-preset-es2015

And I tried adding the module noted here: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/#loaders

None of this changes the output. I've tried a few other minor things too but want to stay as narrowed focused as possible.

**Main Question**: Does this tutorial example work as written?

**Secondary Question**: If not, how to fix it...

Comment: Are you sure you've installed webpack 2 ? Webpack 2 is still in beta so if you run `npm install --save-dev webpack` you will as of now get webpack 1 which doesn't support es6 imports on its own. Webpack 2 does. Check with `./node_modules/.bin/webpack -v`

Comment: @jontem, you are right. I'm accidently using Webpack 1.14 when I meant to use WebPack 2. If you structure this as the answer to my question, I'll market it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've installed Webpack 2 which is still in beta.

If you run `npm install --save-dev webpack` you will as of now get webpack 1 which doesn't support ES6 imports on its own. This is a new feature of Webpack 2.

You can check which webpack version you have installed with: 
`./node_modules/.bin/webpack -v`

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a tutorial that works and really gets you going with webpack, do this one:

http://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/

I would be suspicious of a tutorial that contained lodash, since that's taking you out of the realm of "getting started" pretty fast (I have nothing against lodash, but what does it have to do with webpack hello world).

Also I think what you're trying to do may involve script_loader. But again, stick with the tutorial link I posted above. When you finish that I think you'll see how to include external scripts and such.

Comment: What'd like like is to understand the deficiency in the example provided as my use case will immediately get in to things like import statements. I appreciate the other example suggestion but I'm afraid this is at best an aside.

Comment: import statements would be part of any tutorial involving webpack I think. I'd recommend looking at that tutorial since it does address loaders.

Answer (score 0):

In the webpack.config.js file, adding the following worked:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

If you are following the tutorial, you'll also need add the following packages (apparently) as described by https://github.com/babel/babel-loader (This topic is touched on here https://webpack.js.org/concepts/#loaders but I can't figure out if it's out of date given the latest version or if it was not working for some other reason)

`npm install babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev`

The whole completed webpack.config.js file looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: './dist'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```